# jquery onclick child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a button that has an even attached to the anchor element. When I'm clicking on the span inside the anchor the event is getting fired as intended. The problem I have is that the function is using the span as the element that triggered the event. Here is my UI code:

```
<a href="" class="col-xs-4 text-center facebook-share" style="background-color:yellow" data-share="facebook" data-title="Check this out, yo" data-image="my-image" data-link="my-url" data-description="Nice, very nice" href="#">
    <span class="like">LIKE</span>
    <span class="sep">/</span>
    <span class="like-count count">0</span>
</a>
```

And here is the event handler from the library I'm using:

```
events: function() {

            var self = this;

            this.element.on('click', 'a[data-share]', function( e ) {

                e.preventDefault();

                var $el = $(e.target);

                switch ( $el.data('share') ) {
                    case 'facebook': self.facebook( $el ); break;
                    case 'twitter': self.twitter( $el ); break;
                    case 'googleplus': self.googleplus( $el ); break;
                }

                $el.blur();

            });

            if ( this.options.facebook.appID ) {

                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({appId: self.options.facebook.appID, status: false});
                };

            }

        }
```

In this $el is the span which then means there is no data. Should the event be propagating up to the anchor? What can I do to ensure this happens?

Comment: You're trying to do too much in an anchor tag. It would be much simpler and easier to maintain if you separated it into individual tags with their own unique id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `this` instead on `e.target` because the target can be a descendent of the element the event was registered for (here the `a[data-share]`)

see also [JQuery Event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: Just realised that about 1 minute before I came back here. Reading up on bubbling and the jQuery on event handler helped me work it out. Glad you've confirmed. Note to self, don't not code for 18 months! I've forgotten so much of this simple stuff!